# Build OSX .pkg file on linux

Tags: macos, ubuntu, pkgbuild, pkg-file

May I ask what's the practical option to build .pkg file on ubuntu? I was trying xar, but the resulted .pkg file could not be installed on mac, got 'com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1'
And I was trying to use munkipkg, but it depends on `pkgbuild` on OS X.
Is that possible to have pkgbuild on linux? or could anyone suggest a best way to do this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to do. Here's a [tutorial on how to make it work](https://web.archive.org/web/20160528161248/http://bomutils.dyndns.org/tutorial.html).

You essentially need to use `xar`, but you also need a BOM (bill of materials), which the tool will create for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene, but after I tried it and pack the package, when I was trying to install the package on a mac OS X, I got
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1.)" Could you please suggest on that?

Comment: I think this approach will work, that error was my fault giving wrong Distribution file. Still have some other errors:P

Comment: when I try to install the package, I got "Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 'An error occurred while running scripts from the package ...'", do you have any idea how could I solve that? thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably one of two things. 1) You need to make sure the user:group permissions of the BOM, XAR, and output pkg are the same. 2) Maybe add file permission +x to the .pkg

Comment: hey Eugene, I tried to set permission +x to every file, and the owner from cpio set to 0:80, but still get the error :(

Comment: @lucky_start_izumi I don't know then, I'd advise creating a new post about that where you can post the full log.

Comment: It's working, the error was because of my structure :P The bounty could only be given in 16hours, will do that tomorrow thanks so much!

Comment: @lucky_start_izumi glad to know it worked. Can maybe edit your post to say what the structure issues were for future people.

Comment: I guess my useless isn't really typical, because the content is copied here, we didn't have correct Distribution file & PackageInfo file. After changed on those it worked

Comment: But what about the XML files? like the one that contain the paths, file sizes, permissions, etc?

Comment: I was able to create my installations using the guide. But recently I've moved to new Ubuntu 22 and there is a problem with XAR because it uses libssl1.0-dev which was removed from ubuntu.